Forcing right to left text direction in Xcode UI test prevents sliders from moving
I'm using the following code to launch a UI test that forces a specific app language and moves a slider.
I noticed that when forcing right to left text direction (for Arabic or Hebrew), during the UI test the slider doesn't move.
The app content:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var slider = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $slider, in: 0.0...1.0)
    }
}

The UI test:
final class problemUITests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let locale = Locale(identifier: "ar")
        app.launchArguments += ["-AppleLanguages", "(ar)", "-AppleLocale", "ar"]
        if locale.language.characterDirection == .rightToLeft {
            app.launchArguments += ["-NSForceRightToLeftWritingDirection", "YES", "-AppleTextDirection", "YES"]
        }
        app.launch()
        app.sliders.element.adjust(toNormalizedSliderPosition: 0.3)
    }
}

Am I missing something or is there a workaround?
